# Read 4 lines at a time

Tags: python, file-io, lines, fastq

I am trying to read a fastq file four lines at a time. There are several lines in the file. but when I put in my code, I get this:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "fastq.py", line 11, in
>
> line1 = fastq_file.readline()
>
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'readline'

This is my code:

```
import Tkinter, tkFileDialog #asks user to select a file

root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()

fastq_file = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()

if fastq_file.endswith('.fastq'): #check the file extension
    minq = raw_input("What is your minimum Q value? It must be a numerical value.") #receives the minimum Q value
    while True:
        line1 = fastq_file.readline()
        if not line1:break
        line2 = fastq_file.readline(2)
        line3 = fastq_file.readline(3)
        line4 = fastq_file.readline(4)
    
    txt = open(practice.text)   
    txt.write(line1) #puts the lines into the file
    txt.write("\n")
    txt.write(line2)
    txt.write("\n")
    txt.write(line3)
    txt.write("\n")
    txt.write(line4)
    txt.write("\n")
    print "Your task is complete!"
    
else:
  print "The file format is not compatible with the FastQ reader program. Please check the file and try again."
```

How would I fix it so that I can assign each line to a string and then write those strings in a text file?

Comment: How you define `fastq_file` ? Lemme see your full code.

Comment: `fastq_file` isn't what you think it is. It looks like you have a file name, and you haven't opened it yet, so `fastq_file` is just a string. But we can't tell without seeing where `fastq_file` is defined.

Comment: Also your question does not mention multithreading anywhere. If it's not actually applicable to the question, please untag it.

Comment: And the argument to readline isn't what you think it is. You should read the documentation.

Comment: I added in all of my code in the question now. How would I fix it? Sorry, this is my first program.

Comment: Are you trying to use Tkinter just to read the file name? If so, you can start by removing every Tkinter line from your program, use the suggestion in the current answers and go from there. But if you really want to build a GUI, you're in way over your head. Nothing wrong with a challenge, but you must read the documentation for Tkinter, or a good tutorial, and come back if you have specific questions.

Comment: @user2612453 this is not to demotivate you, if this is your first programme, GUI programming would be hard for you. Better use simple `raw_input` to take input from terminal.

Answer (score 1):

You need to open the file first

```
while True:
    with open(fastq_file) as fastq_file_open:
        line1 = fastq_file_open.readline()
```

You probably want to open them before you actually get to the while loop, but I don't have the rest of your code, so I can't structure it that exactly.

Comment: I don't get the `while True:` part. This code will just keep opening and reading 1 line forever.

Comment: I added in all of my code in the question now. How would I fix it? Sorry, this is my first program.

Answer (score 1):

You have to open the file like this.

```
fastq_file = open("fastq_file","r")
```

Then execute your code.

And also.

```
txt = open("practice.text","w") # you have to pass a string and open it in write mode.
```

By the way, you don't need to use `readline(<number>)`, it only reads `<number>` characters from the current cursor position. After executing one `readline()`, the cursor moves to after next newline character and for next `readline()`, it starts to read from there. So just use `readline()`.

Anyway I don't know what you are trying to achieve. But the code looks like you are trying to copying the context from `fastq_file` to `practice.text`, which can be done just by copying the file (using `shutil.copyfile`).

Comment: I added in all of my code in the question now. How would I fix it? Sorry, this is my first program.

Comment: still not clear. The code looks like you are copying the file to `practice.txt`. I ask you, what is the significance that you are reading four lines at every loop ?

Answer (score -1):

what is fastq_file? your code is incorrect. if, fastq_file were a file descriptor, it cannot be an str object.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. Please comment on the original question next time.